# modifying an existing argparse parser - specifically, removing a positional

Tags: python, argparse

It's pretty common for me to write command line programs that rely on the processing already defined in another, with some tweaks to behavior.

When that requires adding an argument, I may do something like:

```
@classmethod
def modify_parser(cls, parser):
    dest="node"
    default="root"
    parser.add_argument(
        "--" + dest,
        action="store",
        help="%s node to list[%s]" % (dest,default)
        )
```

I am not writing a subcommand, I am just adding an option to the existing parser.  Works fine.

OK, but let's say I want to remove an option.  Let's take the below argparse help message:

```
usage: test_dumper3.py [-h] 
                       [--Database DBNAME]
                       config [recname [recname ...]]

dump out tables

positional arguments:
  config                config file   <<<< I DONT WANT THIS!
  recname                             <<<< because this replaces it
....
```

This is my first attempt:

```
@classmethod
def modify_parser(cls, parser):

    dest="recname"
    parser.add_argument(
        dest,
        nargs="*",
        action="store",
        help=dest
        )
    parser._positionals._remove_action("config")
```

And I get `ValueError('list.remove(x): x not in list',)`.

I am guessing that you need to pass in the argparse.Action instance to remove, not its name.  Is there somewhere where I can look that up?  Something like `action_to_delete = parser.get_action('config')` and then `parser._positionals._remove_action(action_to_delete)`?

I don't really mind the risk associated with messing with `_` private attributes, just experimenting a bit with argparse.

Comment: `_remove_action` is only used by `_handle_conflict_resolve`, which is used when you set the `conflict_handler` to `resolve` (as opposed to the default 'error').  It takes an `Action` object as argument, not its `dest`.  The full list of `Actions` is `parser._actions`.  Look at the code for `_remove_action` (it's defined in 3 classes).

Comment: `add_argument` returns the newly created `Action` object (besides putting in in the `_actions` list.  Your `modify_parser` function could be return that reference, and you could hang on to that for future use.

Comment: An `Acton` object has attributes like `dest`, `nargs` and `default`.  You can view those, and even modify them.  So you might not have remove the old action, but just change its `dest`.  I like testing ideas like this an interactive session where I can examine objects and make changes directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove an action from an existing argumentparser with something like the following:

```
config_action = [action for action in parser._actions if action.dest=="config"]
parser._optionals._actions._remove_action(config_action)
```

Comment: apologies, I've mostly switched to [click](https://pypi.org/project/click/) nowadays, so I can't really check if you're right.  +1 and I will accept if someone else currently using argparse confirms this works.